# Single JSON with array that contains other JSON

Tags: javascript, json, hierarchy

I'm in trouble with JSON objects.
I have to create a JSN like this:

```
{
 name: 'root',
 children: [
     name: 'son1',
     children: [....]
 ]
}
```

How can I build it using Javascript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand what you need here... what do you mean by "build it using javascript"? You want to convert your current object to JSON?

Comment: Using Javascript syntax...I would to create it looping on my data

Comment: only change `children`, that is an invalid array, to an object `children: {name: 'son1', children: {...}}`, and be aware that this is not a JSON, it is just an object

Comment: Seems like you don't know what JSON is?

Comment: @chrispbacon what is wrong? I don't even understand what OP wants, I'm just saying that `children` is invalid and his current object is not json

Comment: I know that is a strange JSON, but this structure specific JSON structure needs to render a tree with a Vue.js component

Comment: This is the component that i would use: https://vuejsexamples.com/a-vue2-component-to-display-tree-chart/

Comment: @CalvinNunes children needs to be an array - an array of objects though (so your comment isn't completely wrong, only partially)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean build out using objects? 
And then call `JSON.stringify()`

```js
function MyObject(name) {
  this.name = name,
  this.children = [],
  this.addChild = (child) => {
    this.children.push(child);
  }
}

const root = new MyObject("root");

for(let x=0; x<10; x++) {
  let child = new MyObject(`child ${x}`);
  root.addChild(child);
}

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(root);
```

```html
<pre>

</pre>
```